# Convert from IEEE 754-2008 decimal floating point data to binary floating point format

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

I have a binary data on the disk stored in IEEE 754-2008 format which is the 32-bit floating point with base 10 exponent (if I got it right: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point). How would I convert it to base 2 floating point (like the standard float32 on intel processors)? Sample code in C, Python or Java would be great! Thanks for help!

Comment: There are 2 variants: binary integer significand field, densely packed decimal significand field.  Which one is used?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GCC, you may have access to dedicated decimal float routines: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Decimal-float-library-routines.html

You should deserialize your binary data into one of the decimal float types and then apply the conversion function to standard floating point types.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I get an error:
error: decimal floating point not supported for this target
when I try to define _Decimal32 variable. I guess it is not supported on Intel platform???

Comment: It is, but your compiler may not support it. When you build GCC from source, you have the option to enable or disable decimal float support; I recommend recompiling GCC to be sure to have it. (That's very straight-forward, don't worry.)

Comment: Thanks. I should try it. Is it also supported on Darwin?

Comment: You can definitely *build* GCC on Darwin, but the type of decimal float that's supported there may be a different one. (Apparently there are two common types.) Anyway, if all you need is to *read* some binary data, perhaps you'd be faster off just parsing the thing manually. The point about GCC is that it can actually perform operations with decimals, but if you don't need that anyway, that might be overkill.